# Initialising C structures in C++ code

Tags: c++, c, initialization, structure

Is there a better way to initialise C structures in C++ code?

I can use initialiser lists at the variable declaration point; however, this isn't that useful if all arguments are not known at compile time, or if I'm not declaring a local/global instance, eg:

Legacy C code which declares the struct, and also has API's using it

```
typedef struct
{
    int x, y, z;
} MyStruct;
```

C++ code using the C library

```
void doSomething(std::vector<MyStruct> &items)
{
    items.push_back(MyStruct(5,rand()%100,items.size()));//doesn't work because there is no such constructor
    items.push_back({5,rand()%100,items.size()});//not allowed either

    //works, but much more to write...
    MyStruct v;
    v.x = 5;
    v.y = rand()%100;
    v.z = items.size();
    items.push_back(v);
}
```

Creating local instances and then setting each member one at a time (`myStruct.x = 5;` etc) is a real pain, and somewhat hard to read when trying to add say 20 different items to the container...

Comment: are you looking for a solution in C or C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't add a constructor (which is the best solution in C++03 but you probably have compatibility constraint with C), you can write a function with the same effect:

```
MyStruct makeAMyStruct(int x, int y, int z)
{
    MyStruct result = { x, y, z };
    return result;
}

items.push_back(makeAMyStruct(5,rand()%100,items.size()));
```

Edit: I'd have checked now that C++0X offers something for this precise problem:

```
items.push_back(MyStruct{5,rand()%100,items.size()});
```

which is available in g++ 4.4.

Comment: btw: why not use an initialization list?

Comment: "...C++0X offers something..." does this feature have a name that I could use to search for more info?

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for C99 compound literals. Example code:

```
struct foo *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
*foo = (struct foo){ bar, baz };
```

Comment: Sounds like a great solution, if it was supported by the compiler (VC++9) :(

Comment: this time, it's actually not the compiler's fault as compound literals are a C99 feature unsupported by C++; I misread your question and thought you were looking for a solution in C...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language/1705166#1705166 for some explanations and the C++0x syntax

Comment: Complain to MS that their C compiler is archaic because it is only supporting a twenty year old standard, not the ten year old replacement standard.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
MyStruct v = {5, rand()%100, items.size()};
items.push_back(v);
```

Comment: So to do multiple things ill have to do v1,v2,v3,v4 etc, no way to reuse the one local?

Comment: If you have v1, v2, v3, and v4, you are stuck with writing something out 4 times - unless you want them to have the same value, in which case you can do simple assignments, of course.  If you had v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3] and v[4], then you could use a loop instead.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think:
MyStruct vs[2] = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}; will work

Answer (score 3):

Create a function to initialize it, similar to what a C++ constructor would do.

Comment: (+1) KISS answer from all perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what you are asking. In C++, the obvious solution is to give the struct a constructor:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int x, y, z;
  MyStruct( int ax, int ay, int az ) : x( ax ), y( ay ), z( az ) {}
};
```

Comment: he's looking for a solution in C

Comment: Then why's he tagged it C++? This is why I said I wasn't clear.

Comment: My guess is that he has headers which have to stay in C (legacy code shared between projects) but he want a convenient way of using the struct in C++.

Comment: The thing is its a struct in some legacy C code, so unless there is some way to retrospectively add the constructor (i.e. without breaking compatibility with the C library the struct is for, and ideally without editing the declaration in the c headers themselves)?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to derive from the struct and add a constructor there.

```
struct MyDerivedStruct : public MyStruct
{
    MyDerivedStruct(int xi, int yi, int zi)
    {
        x = xi;
        y = yi;
        z = zi;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this derived type in your own code and pass it to the C library when necessary. The language should take care of implicitly converting to `MyStruct` when appropriate.

As a bonus, you could also add other useful member functions, perhaps even wrapping many of the legacy C functions that use this type.