# C equivalent of new Object(constructor)

Tags: c++, c

What's the C equivalent (with malloc) of the following

```
MyClass* ptr = new MyClass(arg1,arg2);
```

The first thing that comes to my mind is to instantiate a MyClass object on the stack, then do a `malloc(sizeof(MyClass));` and then a `memcpy(stack, to_malloc'd_memory)`

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: There's no class in C - what, apart from malloc, do you want to do? Just initialize the allocated memory via `ptr->... = arg1`

Comment: typically, just call `calloc()` - this allocates space and sets all the bytes to zero. If you need to specifically set values, then individually set the fields.

Comment: Introduce a function `make_my_class` that you can call as `MyClass *ptr = make_my_class(arg1, arg2);`

Comment: Asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774193/constructor-for-structs-in-c Good practice is to make functions similar to constructors (initializers) with name identical to name of structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent (or replacement) of a constructor in C is an initializer. You can use such an initializer in the construction of a compound literal (another C speciality) and by that initialize your new object by assignment.

```
MyClass* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
*ptr = (MyClass){ .a = 1, .b = 34 };
```

a convention to do so systematically could be to always have an "init" function

```
inline
MyClass* MyClass_init(MyClass* ptr, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) {
   if (ptr) {
     *ptr = (MyClass){ .a = arg1, .b = arg2, };
   }
   return ptr;
}
```

and then to call that at initialization of the pointer

```
MyClass* ptr = MyClass_init(malloc(sizeof *ptr), arg1,arg2);
```

Comment: Which compiler supports this: `*ptr = (MyClass){ .a = 1, .b = 34 };`? Is this standard?

Comment: @JeffRSon it's standard C99.

Comment: Seems like neither VS2012 nor VS2013 supports it.

Comment: @JeffRSon, MS refuses to implement newer C standards in their compilers. They are pretty much alone on this nowadays. Just don't use their compilers for C.

Comment: Yes - it seems they are more into C++11 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99), although they emphasize C99 library support: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is none. You might follow this scheme:

```
typedef struct NamespaceClassData {
    ...
} NamespaceClass;

NamespaceClass* namespace_class_create(T arg1, U arg2) {
   // malloc and initialize
}

void namespace_class_destroy(MyClass* p) {
   // destroy and free
}
```

Note: While struct X is a type in C++, it is just a tag in C (hence the typedef struct)

Answer (score 1):

This is not easily done, since `malloc` (or the C language itself) is not aware of something like "constructors".

Note that the following workaround is **not safe** for anything related to memory management.

```
MyClass* ptr = malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
*ptr = MyClass(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply put whatever data you *need* into the `malloc`ed memory -- *that's* what construction *is*.

Answer (score 0):

this would only work if your class is very simply, and support shallow copy.
I didnt write c code for some time now, but what I would do,is create an init function( init () ), that will act like ctor, and create a macro that will allocate the memory (maloc), and then call the init ( ##init() ).
something like:

```
  1 #define NEW(TYPE, NAME) malloc(sizeof(TYPE));\
  2                         init_ ##TYPE(NAME);
```