# C code involving {}

Tags: c, curly-braces, static-initializer

I saw this in some C code:

```
Wininfo W = { sizeof(Wininfo) };
```

What the heck does this mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code is initializing a `struct` using funky C initializer syntax to initialize each field in order of declaration, see http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=421. An important side-effect in the case of this example is that remaining fields one doesnt specify values for get initialized to zeros.

This trick is a relatively common one in Win32 APIs - the API requires the size to be pre-set as a way of indicating the version the client code is compiled against - in many of these cases, one is also expected to clear the buffer, which would ordinarily involve a separate call to e.g. `memset` prior to initializing the size field with the `sizeof`.

See also [Struct initialization of the C/C++ programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language) for related examples

Answer (score 9):

It's an [initializer expression](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/strin.htm) that sets the first field of `W` to `sizeof(Wininfo)` and the other fields to zero.

Comment: +1 (and stole most of the answer to make mine a lot less incomplete :P)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it is not a statement, it is a declaration. Declarations are not statements in C.

Secondly, the `= { /* whatever */ }` part is an *initializer* - it specifies the initial value of an object. Normally you use initializers enclosed in `{}` to initialize aggregate objects: arrays or structs. However, a little-known feature of C language is that initializers of scalar objects can also be optionally enclosed in `{}`, as in

```
int i = { 5 };
```

What exactly your specific declaration means depends on what `Wininfo` type is. If `W` is an aggregate, then its first member is initialized with `sizeof(Wininfo)` value and the rest is initialized with zeroes. If `W` is a scalar, then it just gets the initial value of `sizeof(Wininfo)`.

Comment: Since it includes an initializer, it's not just a declaration, but a definition.

Comment: Definition is always a declaration. So, it contexts when the distinction is of no importance, the term *declaration* is normally used. The syntactic element is always called *declaration*. Definitions only exist at the level of semantics.

Comment: +1: Nice and complete (@nos: this is what I was angling at when mentioning redundant)