# Can C struct assignment use brace syntax?

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Struct initialization of the C/C++ programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language)

I'm re-learning C and asking myself if something like this is possible:

```
typedef struct Link {
    struct Node a;
    struct Node b;
    float weight;
    } Link;

Link links[LINK_NUMBER];
links[0] = {nodes[0], nodes[1], 5};
```

instead of:

```
Link link0 = {nodes[0], nodes[1], 5};
links[0] = link;
```

Comment: @Juliano: I found the solution in this topic - see below. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's what I was searching for:

```
links[0] = (Link) {nodes[0], nodes[1], 5};
```

Comment: Note that this is only valid in C99 and GNU C. Many legacy compilers will not understand this syntax. I mentioned this in the original question this one is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if structs can be assigned? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: the question was actually if it is possible to use the brace syntax in assignments.

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't work because a `Link` can't contain another `Link`.

However, it can contain a *pointer* to another `Link` (a `Link*`).

Regarding the assignment: You can only use the brace syntax when *initializing* a value, not when *setting* a value. (I believe this changes in C++0x/C++11, though.)

Comment: C99 supports structure literals, which can be used in assignments.