# Initialisation of a CGPoint with { } notation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, cgpoint

After `CGPointMake` let me down I found out that we can initalise a static const `CGPoint` like this instead:

```
static const CGPoint p = { 0.f, 0.f };
```

It works but what is the curly bracket notation actually doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CGPoint is a struct:

```
struct CGPoint {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
};
```

It's a valid method to initialize a struct in C. See [Struct initialization of the C/C++ programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language).

Comment: Do you think struct initialization will work faster than `CGPointMake` function call?