# Why a C-style typecasting is mandatory while initializing a POD data in initializer list?

Tags: c++

```
struct POD { int i, j; };    
class A {
  POD m_pod;
public:
  A() : m_pod({1,2}) {} // error
  A() : m_pod(static_cast<POD>({1,2})) {} // error
  A() : m_pod((POD) {1,2}) {} // ok!
};
```

I see this in an old production code compiled with `g++34`, until then I din't know this feature.
Is it a [g++](http://ideone.com/292Le) specific feature ?  If not then, why is typecasting needed and that's too only C-style cast is allowed ?

Comment: My guess is `{1,2}` is not a POD type and a `reinterpret_cast` is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you're using isn't just for initializer lists, it's for any initialization of class types outside of their declarations. For example:

```
POD p;
p = (POD) {1, 2};
```

These are called **compound literals**; they were added to C in C99. They aren't actually supported in C++; GCC allows them in C++ (and C89) as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). C++11 [adds the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705166/309308):

```
p = POD({1, 2});
```

Or in your case:

```
A() : m_pod(POD({1,2})) {}
```

Comment: I also didn't know that GCC allows `POD p; p = (POD) {1, 2};` syntax. All answers are good; accepting this for usefule information regarding the extensions.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the following syntax is not allowed by C++ Standard (both C++03, and C++11):

```
A() : m_pod((POD) {1,2}) {} // ok!
```

Since GCC compiles this, it is a GCC extension.

If you compile it with `-pedantic` option, it gives this warning:

> pod.cpp:8:29: warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals

---

In C++11, you can write this:

```
A() : m_pod{1,2} {}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/XaO4y

Or simply this:

```
class A {
  POD m_pod {1,2}; //in-place initialization
public:
  A() {}
};
```

Ideone doesn't support this though.