# Initializing structs inside a struct with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Here is my data structure for an NPC.

```
typedef struct npc {
   npc_characteristics_t characteristics;
   position pc_last_known_position;
   position npc_position;
   int speed;
   int turn;
} npc_t;
```

I initialize it with this:

```
void gen_monsters(dungeon *d, int nummon) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < nummon; i++) {
    npc_t *monster;
    if (!(monster = malloc(sizeof (*monster)))) {
      perror("malloc");
      exit(1);
    } else {
      init_monster(monster);
    }
  }
}

static void init_monster(npc_t *m) {
  int charact = rand()%3;

  if (charact == 0) 
    m->characteristics = 0x00000000;
  else if (charact == 1)
    m->characteristics = NPC_SMART;
  else if (charact == 2)
    m->characteristics = NPC_TELEPATH;

  m->pc_last_known_position = {0, 0};
  m->npc_position = {0, 0};
  m->speed = rand() % 15 + 6;
  m->turn = 0;
}
```

And this is my `position` struct:

```
typedef struct position_t {
  int x, y;
} position;
```

Why isn't this working? I'm getting this:

```
npc.c:22:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
npc.c: In function ‘init_monster’:
npc.c:35:30: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  m->pc_last_known_position = {0,0};
                          ^
npc.c:37:20: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  m->npc_position = {0,0};
                    ^
make: *** [npc.o] Error 1
```

And what's the correct way to do this? I'm supposed to use `malloc` to get some room in memory for the structure right? But then wouldn't I need to do this for `position` also and give the NPC the pointer to the `position` struct?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can't use an initializer list that way, you can use the `memset()` function from the `string.h` header, this way

```
memset(&(m->pc_last_known_position), 0, sizeof(m->pc_last_known_position));
memset(&(m->npc_position), 0, sizeof(m->pc_last_known_position));
```