# C programming structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    struct Record {
        int employeeNumber;
        char employeeName;
        float salary;
        int yearsServiced;  
    } record[5];

    struct record[0] = {46723, "Fattah", 4550.00, 8};
    printf("TheEmployee number is %d", record[0].employeeNumber);

}
```

**Why my program cannot run? please help. Thanks for advance.**

Comment: `struct record[0]` declares an array of size 0.

Comment: `char employeeName;` --> `char *employeeName;`, `struct record[0] = {46723, "Fattah", 4550.00, 8};` --> `record[0] = (struct Record){46723, "Fattah", 4550.00, 8};`

Comment: I dun understand. Please explain more. Why need to cast (struct Record)?

Comment: @TeoPeiShen don't listen the solution of BLUEPIXY, it's correct but that will confuse you in this state.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... your question whilst it may be answered does not help anyone experiencing similar issues in the future and adds nothing to StackOverflow.

Comment: @TeoPeiShen _Why need to cast (struct Record)?_ It means compound literals, not casts.

Comment: Also, you can implement with array initialization list. E.g `} record[5];` --> `} record[5] = { {46723, "Fattah", 4550.00, 8} };`

Comment: You can not use an initialization list as an assignment expression to an array element. For the sake of convenience, you can use a compound literal to make a similar writing as shown above. However, it can not be used in older versions of C. You need to use the initialization list at declaration or use an assignment expression for each member.

Comment: Thanks BlUEPIXY. the casting way works because I got 5 more struct to key in. record[0]=(struc Record){1234,"Fattah",7845.98,8} works from record[0] to record[4].

Answer (score 1):

`struct record[0]` declares an array of size 0. You intend to initialize the first element of the array and you confuse declaring and indexing:

```
struct Record myRecord[1] = {46723, "Fattah", 4550.00, 8};
```

This declares an array of size 1 and initializes the first element with the given values.

Comment: So, the struct array is not like int array or char array that starts from [0]?Thanks for fast response.

Comment: `struct record[1]` --> `struct Record record[1]` (And use another name for variable name of the array)

Comment: @Bluepix, thanks. fixed that.

Comment: Moreover, it seems that the type of `employeeName` is wrong.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main (){
 struct Record{
 int employeeNumber;
 char employeeName;
 float salary;
 int yearsServiced; 
 } record[5];
 
 struct record[1] ={46723,"Fattah",4550.00,8};
 printf("TheEmployee number is %d",record[1].employeeNumber);

}

Comment: Still cannot run.10 15 C:\Users\teopeishen\Desktop\Question2.c [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '[' token

Comment: Sorry, my problem. struct Record myRecord[1] does work. Just I forget to declare employeeName as array.

Comment: But I still dun understand how it works? Can you recommend any resources?

Answer (score 0):

You declared employeeName as char but you pass in a string. employeeName needs to be a pointer on char.

char *employeeName;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    struct Record {
        int employeeNumber;
        char *employeeName;
        float salary;
        int yearsServiced;  
    } record[5];

record[0].employeeNumber = 46723;
    record[0].employeeName = "Fattah";
    record[0].salary = 4550.00;
    record[0].yearsServiced = 8;

    printf("TheEmployee number is %d", record[0].employeeNumber);

}
```

Comment: I understand your solution but do you have way i can construct all the elements in one line. Thanks for your fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by `struct record[0]` you are declaring an array of size 0, which you need to change to `struct record[1]`.

And as far as your doubt regarding casting, you should read [Struct initialization of the C/C++ programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705147/struct-initialization-of-the-c-c-programming-language)

Lastly , I don't think it is the reason of your error but why are you trying to assign `"Fattah"` to a variable of type `char`.